# How do I get the next button to cycle through tabs in jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, css

So I have these tabs that I am trying to get some < prev and next > links to work with so when the user is at the bottom of the tab and clicks next it will open up the next tab. Seems simple enough but I'm not sure why they wont work. 
I have built a jsfiddle with the code that I am using for the tabs and also for the next and prev links here:

https://jsfiddle.net/NoJqueryMaster/6Ltsphf7/61/

Sorry for the lengthy post, figured it would help for clarity sake.
Like I mentioned, what I am trying to achieve is simply click the next link and it opens the next tab.

```js
//Fancy tabs selection
var numItems = $('li.fancyTab').length;
if (numItems == 12) {
  $("li.fancyTab").width('8.3%');
}
if (numItems == 11) {
  $("li.fancyTab").width('9%');
}
if (numItems == 10) {
  $("li.fancyTab").width('10%');
}
if (numItems == 9) {
  $("li.fancyTab").width('11.1%');
}
if (numItems == 8) {
  $("li.fancyTab").width('12.5%');
}
if (numItems == 7) {
  $("li.fancyTab").width('14.2%');
}
if (numItems == 6) {
  $("li.fancyTab").width('16.666666666666667%');
}
if (numItems == 5) {
  $("li.fancyTab").width('20%');
}
if (numItems == 4) {
  $("li.fancyTab").width('25%');
}
if (numItems == 3) {
  $("li.fancyTab").width('33.3%');
}
if (numItems == 2) {
  $("li.fancyTab").width('50%');
}

$(window).load(function() {

  $('.fancyTabs').each(function() {

    var highestBox = 0;
    $('.fancyTab a', this).each(function() {

      if ($(this).height() > highestBox)
        highestBox = $(this).height();
    });

    $('.fancyTab a', this).height(highestBox);

  });
});


   

$("#tabs").tabs();
            $(".nexttab").click(function() {
        let indexActiveTab = $('#fancyTabWidget .tab ').find('.active').eq();
   $('#fancyTabWidget .tab ').removeClass('active');
   $('#fancyTabWidget .tab:eq('+indexActiveTab+1+') ').addClass('.active');
  //alert(selected);
  var selected = $("#tabs").tabs("option", "selected");
  $("#tabs").tabs("option", "selected", selected + 1);
 });
 $(".prevtab").click(function() {
  let indexActiveTab = $('#fancyTabWidget .tab ').find('.active').eq();
  $('#fancyTabWidget .tab ').removeClass('active');
  $('#fancyTabWidget .tab:eq('+indexActiveTab-1+') ').addClass('.active');
  var selected = $("#tabs").tabs("option", "selected");
        $("#tabs").tabs("option", "selected", selected - 1);
 });
```

```css
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  font-weight: 700;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none !important;
  color: #333 !important;
}

.fancyTab {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 15px 0;
  background-color: #eee;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #ddd;
  top: 15px;
  transition: top 0.2s;
}

.fancyTab.active {
  top: 0;
  transition: top 0.2s;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 0 1px #fff, 0 0px 0 1px #ddd, -1px 1px 0 0px #ddd inset;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
}

.whiteBlock {
  display: none;
}

.fancyTab.active .whiteBlock {
  display: block;
  height: 2px;
  bottom: -2px;
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 99%;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}

.fancyTab a {
  font-size: 1.65em;
  font-weight: 300;
  transition: 0.2s;
  color: #333;
}

.fancyTabs {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #ddd;
  margin: 15px 0 0;
}

li.fancyTab a {
  padding-top: 15px;
  top: -15px;
  padding-bottom: 0;
}

.fancyTab a:focus {
  outline: none;
}

li.fancyTab.active a {
  padding-top: inherit;
}

.fancyTab .fa {
  font-size: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 15px 0 5px;
  color: #666;
}

.fancyTab.active .fa {
  color: #cfb87c;
}

.fancyTabContent {
  border-color: transparent;
  box-shadow: 0 -2px 0 -1px #fff, 0 0 0 1px #ddd;
  padding: 30px 15px 15px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.nav-tabs>li.fancyTab {
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.nav-tabs>li.fancyTab>a {
  margin-right: 0;
  border-top: 0;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  margin-bottom: -30px;
}

.nav-tabs>li.fancyTab:hover a {
  border-color: transparent;
}

.nav-tabs>li.fancyTab:last-child a {
  border-right: 1px solid transparent;
}

.nav-tabs>li.fancyTab.active>a,
.nav-tabs>li.fancyTab.active>a:focus,
.nav-tabs>li.fancyTab.active>a:hover {
  border-width: 0;
}

.nav-tabs>li.fancyTab:hover {
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #ddd;
}

.nav-tabs>li.fancyTab.active:hover {
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 0 1px #fff, 0 0px 0 1px #ddd, -1px 1px 0 0px #ddd inset;
}

.nav.nav-tabs .fancyTab a[data-toggle="tab"] {
  background-color: transparent;
  border-bottom: 0;
}

.nav-tabs>li.fancyTab.active:last-child {
  border-right: 0px solid #ddd;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 0 0px #fff, 0px 0px 0 1px #ddd;
}

.fancyTab:last-child {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #ddd;
}

.tabs .nav-tabs li.fancyTab.active a {
  box-shadow: none;
  top: 0;
}

.arrow-down {
  display: none;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 20px solid transparent;
  border-right: 20px solid transparent;
  border-top: 22px solid #ddd;
  position: absolute;
  top: -1px;
  left: calc(50% - 20px);
}

.arrow-down-inner {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 18px solid transparent;
  border-right: 18px solid transparent;
  border-top: 12px solid #fff;
  position: absolute;
  top: -22px;
  left: -18px;
}

.fancyTab.active .arrow-down {
  display: block;
}

@media (max-width: 1200px) {
  .fancyTab .fa {
    font-size: 36px;
  }
  .fancyTab .hidden-xs {
    font-size: 22px;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 992px) {
  .fancyTab .fa {
    font-size: 33px;
  }
  .fancyTab .hidden-xs {
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: normal;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .fancyTab>a {
    font-size: 18px;
  }
  .nav>li.fancyTab>a {
    padding: 15px 0;
    margin-bottom: inherit;
  }
  .fancyTab .fa {
    font-size: 30px;
  }
  .nav-tabs>li.fancyTab>a {
    border-right: 1px solid transparent;
    padding-bottom: 0;
  }
  .fancyTab.active .fa {
    color: #333;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container-fluid" style="margin-bottom: 50px;">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2 col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-4" style="padding-top:50px;">
      <section id="fancyTabWidget" class="tabs t-tabs">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs fancyTabs" role="tablist">
          <li class="tab fancyTab active">
            <div class="arrow-down">
              <div class="arrow-down-inner"></div>
            </div>
            <a id="tab0" href="#tabBody0" role="tab" aria-controls="tabBody0" aria-selected="true" data-toggle="tab" tabindex="0"><span class="fa fa-bars"></span><span class="hidden-xs">Details</span></a>
            <div class="whiteBlock"></div>
          </li>

          <li class="tab fancyTab">
            <div class="arrow-down">
              <div class="arrow-down-inner"></div>
            </div>
            <a id="tab1" href="#tabBody1" role="tab" aria-controls="tabBody1" aria-selected="true" data-toggle="tab" tabindex="0"><span class="fa fa-calendar-o"></span><span class="hidden-xs">Plans</span></a>
            <div class="whiteBlock"></div>
          </li>
        </ul>

        <div id="myTabContent" class="tab-content fancyTabContent" aria-live="polite">
          <div class="tab-pane  fade active in" id="tabBody0" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="tab0" aria-hidden="false" tabindex="0">
            <div>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
                  <p>
                    <h2>Details</h2>
                    <div class="panel-group">
                      <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingNine" style="padding:20px;color:#333;">
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="row" style="padding-top: 25px;">
                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                          <a class="nexttab pull-right" href="#"><span class="titleFontAdminTitle">NEXT <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></span></a>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="tab-pane  fade" id="tabBody1" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="tab1" aria-hidden="true" tabindex="0">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-12">
                <p>
                  <div class="row text-center" style="padding-top:25px;">
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                      <div class="panel panel-success">
                        <div class="panel-body text-center">
                          <h2>Plans</h2>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="row" style="padding-top: 25px;">
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                      <a class="prevtab" href="#"><span class="titleFontAdminTitle"><i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i> PREV</span></a>
                      <a class="nexttab pull-right" href="#"><span class="titleFontAdminTitle">NEXT <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></span></a>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: As a side note you don't really need to set the width of the list-items via js: `display: flex` and `flex:1` in CSS will do automatically the job.

Comment: @fcalderan thats good to know, appreciate the insight. Probably cut down on alot of my code. :)

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please edit it into a [mcve]

Comment: Also I would always put jQuery first - you have console errors

Comment: Couple of days i saw something close to what you asking. Maybe this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59620821/6525081

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you should rewrite `$(window).load` with `$(window).on('load', function(){}`, it causes an error (because of old jQuery syntax).
Here is your working fork:

https://jsfiddle.net/hirdbluebird/rdc3so9e/

Basically, your jQuery code is:

```
// On direct tab click
$('.fancyTabs .tab').on('click', function(e) {
  $(this).siblings().removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
})
// On nexttab click
$('#fancyTabWidget .nexttab').on('click', function() {
    $('#fancyTabWidget .tab.active').removeClass('active').next().tab('show');
})
// On prev tab click
$('#fancyTabWidget .prevtab').on('click', function() {
    $('#fancyTabWidget .tab.active').removeClass('active').prev().tab('show');
})
```

Answer (score 0):

in click button you can get index of current tab active and remove the class , after that you can add active class to the next or prev index that you have you can find tab by index using eq() jQuery function

```
$(".nexttab").click(function() {
      let indexActiveTab = $('#fancyTabWidget .tab ').find('.active').eq();
      $('#fancyTabWidget .tab ').removeClass('active');
      $('#fancyTabWidget .tab:eq('+indexActiveTab+1+') ').addClass('.active');
      alert(selected);
      var selected = $("#tabs").tabs("option", "selected");
      $("#tabs").tabs("option", "selected", selected + 1);
    });
    $("#tabs").tabs();
    $(".prevtab").click(function() {
        let indexActiveTab = $('#fancyTabWidget .tab ').find('.active').eq();
        $('#fancyTabWidget .tab ').removeClass('active');
        $('#fancyTabWidget .tab:eq('+indexActiveTab-1+') ').addClass('.active');
          var selected = $("#tabs").tabs("option", "selected");
        $("#tabs").tabs("option", "selected", selected - 1);
    });
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: A *`"Hope it helps :)"`* describes nothing about the changes you introduced to help on the question. Please be more descriptive.